# accessing passed variables in node require module without having to export a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

its my first posted question so try and endure if i've not formatted it right!

i have an app i'm working on where i connect to multiple databases one with multiple collections in it, so i want to pass mongoose and my connection(db) to a number of files that contain my mongoose schemas for those different collections, heres my files...

// routes.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var connectionTwo = require('./connectionTwo');

var UserNotifications = require('./models/userNotifications.js')(mongoose, connectionTwo);
var userEvents = require('./models/userEvents.js')(mongoose, connectionTwo);
```

// userNotifications.js(mongoose, connectionTwo)

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userNotificationsSchema = new Schema({
    ID: String,
    etc: String
}, { collection: 'userNotifications' });

module.exports = connectionTwo.model('userNotifications', userNotificationsSchema);
```

// userEvents.js(mongoose, connectionTwo)

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userEventsSchema = new Schema({
    ID: String,
    etc: String
}, { collection: 'userEvents' });

module.exports = connectionTwo.model('userEvents', userEventsSchema);
```

I want to know if its possible to get access to the variables passed to my schema files without having to go about it like such...

```
module.exports = function (mongoose, connectionTwo) {
   // userNotifications.js content / userEvents.js content
}
```

i only want to export the model from these files like so

```
module.exports = connectionTwo.model('userNotifications', userNotificationsSchema);
```

so that back in // routes.js i can easy query mongodb like this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    UserNotifications.find(function(err, docs){
            docs.forEach(function(item){
                console.log(item._id);
            });
            res.send(docs);
        });
});
```

Can anyone advise me the best way to go about this ...? it was working fine previously when i only had one schema/ collection per database, i was requiring mongoose and the db connection within each schema file... but since i've added further schemas/ collections to one of my databases, it was no longer working with that stucture in the sense that it wasnt getting any data from the database, so i assumed it was because i'm connecting to the same database in multiple files, which is how i got around to thinking about passing the connection to each schema file... but i'm currently bewildered by it at the minute...

Thanks in Advance to anyone who can save the day !

Comment: i've managed to get it working since, its still connecting to the database in each schema... but if anyone can suggest a better approach i'd appreciate it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to export a function, you can export an object.

So if I understand you correctly you can do something like

```
module.exports = {
    notification: connectionTwo.model'userNotifications', userNotificationsSchema),
    events: contenctionTwo.model('userEvents', userEventsSchema)
}
```

Comment: sorry i dont think i explained myself clearly... if its possible, or the right way to go about it ?.. i want access to the passed in variables to my schema files without creating a module.exports = function(mongoose, connectionTwo){}; 

basically i just want to return a module.exports = contenctionTwo.model('userEvents', userEventsSchema); from my schema file to route.js not an additional function

Comment: you can do what you are suggesting, but I fail to understand what you want access to.  See how mongoose does it - it is passing you a "class" from which you can create a new instance, and you can call the methods of that class without any problem. So just export what you want access to

Comment: i found were i was going wrong... cheers for sticking with me i thought you couldnt add my model to module.exports if you start the schema file by delclaring an anonumous function on it... cheers !